# Creating contact with two or more phone numbers in android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

How can i create new contact in my contact list programmatically with more than one number? I try the next code:

```
    public static void createNewContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name, String note) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    name) // Name of the person
            .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(
                    ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone) // Number of the person
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build()); // Type of mobile number


            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(
                    ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE, note) // note of the person
                        .build());

    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] res =ctx.getContentResolver().
                applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
```

And in program i write:

```
   createNewContact(context, "+12345", "nameContact");
   createNewContact(context, "+67890", "nameContact");
```

After that there are TWO contacts with name "nameContact". But i need to create ONE contact "nameContact" with two numbers : "+12345" and "+67890".

Comment: Why not insert an array of phones? You can't rely on the contact name, if you want to add phones later you will need the contact id or the uri. For example if you have multiple accounts on your phone who have interacted with a contact then you'll have as many contacts with the same name as you have accounts.

Comment: when i insert array  numbers[] = {"+12345", "+67890" }; and code looks like     withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, numbers), i obtain exception  IllegalArgumentException: bad value type: [Ljava.lang.String;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the time to test but I was thinking about this:

```
   public static void createNewContact(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> phones, String name, String note) {

....

for (String phone : phones) {
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(
                    ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone) // Number of the person
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build()); // Type of mobile number
}
```

....